# CronTab does not have the correct path to my module

Tags: configuration, cron, schedule

I'm trying to set up a small cron job example, which I have problems with.

This is my Observer Class with the method I would like to start via cron

```
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model_Observer
{

    public function startJob($observer)
    {
       Mage::log('Hello World');
    }
}
```

Here's the cron part in my `config.xml`

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <mynamespace_start_job>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>*/5 * * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>mymodule/observer::startJob</model>
            </run>
        </mynamespace_start_job>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

I'm using the AOE scheduler and I setup cron.

So when I want to test my cron job and run it via AOEscheduler I get the following error message via system.log:

```
2015-06-04T18:01:15+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Mymodule/Model/Observer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94

2015-06-04T18:01:15+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Mymodule/Model/Observer.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/html/magento/app/code/local:/var/www/html/magento/app/code/community:/var/www/html/magento/app/code/core:/var/www/html/magento/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
```

As you can see magento is looking for my module in Mage/ instead of Mynamespace/

How can I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your model is in the right path and that you have declared you models folder on your config.xml file like:

> `<models>
>               <mymodule>
>                   <class>mynamespace_mymodule_Model</class>
>               </mymodule>
>   </models>`